# Bird of Paradise leaves dying/drying out with central pallor

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, indoors

Photo 1 was presumably from a spider mite infection that was (hopefully) resolved, but this past week a newer leaf started to deteriorate (photo 2). I water it when it completely dries out in the winter and keep it damp in the spring/summer months. It was recently repotted to a cloth pot but don't know if that would cause any issues. I haven't fertilized it since September. So far no other leaves have had any issues. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image]